# Unique CPU ID on Windows via C++

Tags: c++, windows

Well I would like to get an unique CPU ID so I can get an UNIQUE identification for each machine.
I did check __cpuid() from windows.h library, but the problem is that the ID it gets, it's the ID of all types of CPU, if you have an I3 Core processor and I have an I3 core processor, it will give the same "Unique ID".

Here is what I came up with to make a CPU ID from the __cpuid() that returns the same information on processors of the same type:

```
std::string GetCPUID(){

            int CPUInfo[4] = {-1};
            __cpuid(CPUInfo, 0);
             if (CPUInfo[0] < 4)
            return ""; //Error on retrieving

            stringstream st;
            for(int i = 0; i <= 3; i++){ 
                         st << CPUInfo[i];
                    }

            return st.str();

}
```

I also checked a program called "Hardware ID Extractor" that works fine, it actually returns a UNIQUE CPU ID as the GUI as I wanted, so they made available a DLL so we can extract the CPU ID it generated , I tried everything with the cleanest code with the DLL and following their example but it seems that it returns nothing when ran on Windows 7. a lot of other people were complaining about this on Windows 7 via the DLL, even though the GUI on windows 7 returns the correct CPU ID.

Showing my work in the Hardware ID Extractor,

Here is the site where I downloaded the DLL  (Where I chose the link of C++, VB, .NET): http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-hdd_id/free-download/free%20download.html

And here is the DLL itself to download: http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-hdd_id/free-download/DLL%20compressed/HardwareIDExtractorC.dll

This is the code I got from Hardware ID Extractor (I'm using Visual Studio 2008):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
#include <conio.h>
using namespace std;

int main (){

    char* (__stdcall *GetIDESerialNumber)(BYTE);

    HINSTANCE DllInst = NULL;
    if (DllInst == NULL) DllInst = LoadLibrary("C:\\HardwareIDExtractorC.dll");
    printf( "LoadLibrary error %d\n", GetLastError() );
    if (DllInst) {
        GetIDESerialNumber = (char* (__stdcall*)(BYTE))GetProcAddress(DllInst, "GetIDESerialNumber");

    //Now call the imported function
        cout << "SN: " <<  GetIDESerialNumber(0);   // 0 = first IDE hard drive in your system 
    }else{
        printf(" - Not Loaded");
    }

    _getch();



return 0;
}
```

In the visual studio output it shows that the DLL was executed by saying:

```
'Test.exe': Loaded 'C:\HardwareIDExtractorC.dll', Binary was not built with debug information.
```

And the program output that I get is: `LoadLibrary error 998 - Not loaded`

Someone know what I can do to get a CPU ID Unique, like in the application Hardware ID Extractor? I need to get a CPU ID because if I get HDD information, the user may format their Hard Drive and the program will stop working, as I'm designing it to work only that specified computer.

I'm using Windows 7 32 bits Ultimate and Intel I3 Core Processor (if that helps in anyway).

I hope I was clear in my question.
Thanks in advance!

Comment: The call to LoadLibrary() is failing for some reason. Can you add what the error code from GetLastError() is?

Comment: cpuid does not return a unique id of the processor, it returns CPU capabilities. Also, read this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_Serial_Number#Controversy_about_privacy_issues

Comment: It threw error "LoadLibrary error 998" when I used DllInst = LoadLibrary("C:\\HardwareIDExtractorC.dll");
 printf( "LoadLibrary error %d\n", GetLastError() );

Comment: I looked it up this error, and apparently it's a "NO ACCESS" error,  but my program has total administrator access to access it. what can be wrong?

Comment: *"CPU ID because if I get HDD information, the user may format their Hard Drive and the program will stop working, as I'm designing it to work only that specified computer."*  And what if they upgrade their CPU?  What if they're running in a virtual machine and change virtualization packages?  If you're trying to implement a DRM scheme, *don't*...you'll just create hassles for your legitimate users.  http://www.defectivebydesign.org

Comment: Please just don't do this. You'll just create a series of nightmares for your users, including programs that break after CPU upgrades and programs that they can't use after you go out of business. And the people who want to pirate your software will just modify their system to pass you the same information regardless of what physical CPU is installed. So you won't even stop them.

Comment: @HostileFork, so how do suggest me doing it? and David well I know what you mean, and I actually agree with you, but the thing is my company ordered that way, so I can't vote, they decided it is the best way so all I gotta do, is do it! :/ but I agree with you though. so if you guys have some suggestion on the best way to do it to make it harder to access thru other computers. I will be happy to hear

Comment: Have some value-adding feature (like software updates) that anyone who actually cares about your software will want.  Require the software to be registered to get updates from your server.  If you notice egregious accesses to registered services from too many locations in your log, send the registrant a stern email and/or cut them off from updates.  In other words: exclude non-paying people from some value you *actually* provide instead of designing an intentionally defective product.

Comment: @HostileFork My program doesn't require updates, it does exactly what it needs normally, doesn't require any updates, so your suggestion didn't help much, because once its broken, they have the program working forever.

Comment: Plenty of people who don't resort to these kinds of things make money in software.  And plenty of people who do these kinds of things make little or none.  Making it easy and convenient to purchase your software--and having people like you and want to support you--seems like the higher road than building bugs into your program so they break at unexpected times.  You could also spend your development time on things that aren't intentional bugs. http://hostilefork.com/2011/06/17/virtual-machines-and-the-very-genuine-windows-dis-advantage/

Comment: "I'm designing it to work only that specified computer" - Use CryptoAPI functions for that - private-public key scheme. Binding to certain hardware was an obsolete way from the beginning.

Answer (score 3):

You cannot make this work.  Intel introduced a Processor Serial Number back in the Pentium III design, readable with cpuid.  That raised a huge stink because of [privacy concerns](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Processor_Serial_Number#Controversy_about_privacy_issues) and Intel was forced to back down.  The feature got removed in later Pentium III designs and has never been put back.

You are going to have to use another source for a fingerprint.  Don't use just one, collect a bunch and only declare it invalid when more than one changed.  Use the NIC MAC address, RAM size, disk volume serial number, stuff like that.  There are already thousands of questions about that at SO.

Comment: Hans thanks for the answer, you know this program called "Hardware ID Extractor" it claims it retrieves a CPU ID, a HDD Serial Number, all divided, it doesn't say that it uses a lot of information, and still worked correctly. and they make it available the source code, but its only for purchase. Do you know how this program did it? Thanks!

Comment: The program does it one step at a time!  If you really don't want to pay them (which you probably should, since you're obviously doing this for a commercial project else what's the point?), you'll need to figure out on your own what they did.  Mostly you should probably consider not bothering with this, and just doing some sort of online registration thing like lots of others do these days: send a program serial number to a central server that watches for duplicates in use and invalidates them as needed.

Comment: John Zwinck thanks for the answer, I'm really considering buying it, and you know I use online registration as well, but online registration is not so hard to crack if you simulate a server and alter the incoming data, so I'm adding a little more difficulty so my program doesn't get pirated so easily.

Answer (score 3):

[Hardware ID Extractor](http://www.soft.tahionic.com/download-hdd_id/hardware%20ID%20programmer%27s%20DLL.html) is reliable and easy to use. I have it.
Because I purchased the DLL **and** the source code long time ago I didn't had to purchased the upgrades. I just changed the code by myself.

> Hans thanks for the answer, you know this program called "Hardware ID
>   Extractor" it claims it retrieves a CPU ID

Yes. The DLL provides not only the CPU ID and the HDD IDE ID but many other hardware related statistics (IDs). I have tried it on multiple CPUs (both AMD and Intel) and it works like a charm.

**The scheme**

The cheapest 'protection' is the serial number. That just sucks big time. A single mindless customer makes it available on Internet and everybody has your program FOR FREE! Not mentioning that ‘hackers’ today don’t bother to break your software protection. They will buy your software with a fake credit card and will publish the key on web OR they will buy the software with a valid credit card and then they will use the 30 days money back policy to get the money back. Some mad software resellers such as Plimus (yes, stay away from Plimus) are enforcing this on the software vendors.  Classic serial numbers are as dead as dinosaurs.

The other recommendation, the server-based protection, is also not good at all. A bit harder to cheat by fake credit card ‘hackers’ and also won’t leak keys all over the Internet. But you will lose at least half of your customers because these days everybody has a firewall/antivirus that will block your program from connecting to the server. 
And what about those that are mobile? Or that have only random/rare access to internet? I don't even dare to speak about those that are working behind of the firewall of an institution/company/organization. Most of those companies are 'ruled' by mindless network administrators that cut ANY program except Internet Explorer (not even Firefox) from accessing the Internet. I have been there. I have done that. Believe me, IT IS NIGHTMARE! In other to have a program connected to internet you have to go to administration fill lots of request forms and finally MAYBE, MAYBE, they will let the program access the Internet. Through a proxy maybe.

Anyway, it is quite easy to do a reliable key-based based protection for your program: send a key to the customer BUT don't send a classic key but a hardware-based key. This way the key will work only in that SPECIFIC system. You can even post an announcement on your web site: "Please feel free to make this key public. I don't give a damn" :)

Just don't rely on a single hardware ID (CPU only for example) but on all of them. Allow the user to change/upgrade all its hardware components except one. So, as long as they won't change the entire computer the license will work. Since a new computer is purchased every 3.4 years (I have found the statistics on Internet) you should allow the user to ask for 3 new keys (license reactivation). Probably you will release a new version before the 3.4 years interval expires. So, the customers will have to buy the upgrade and get a new key anyway.

Comment: This is the answer I've been looking for. Fella you know I agree with you completely, but the thing is my application is for very specific people and they have to be online because the program is to make HTTP requests so even if I don't put a online login they would have to allow the HTTP Requests from my application, and I'm not only relying on it, I'm just using as an extra protection. By the way, could you post a working example of that DLL in C++? I put an example here but didn't work, I'm using VS 2008, and if you want to upload the Full DLL and gimme I would be very happy haha, Thanks!

Comment: oh yea and I use a pretty secure system with public key and private key login every time the program run, but still I need that CPU thing, the users that are going to use my software will have the machine that I tell them that work, so it's not for normal users. that's why it's ok to be a little complex.

Comment: Please be warned that the CPU ID that "Hardware ID Extractor" gives you is NOTHING MORE than the RAW output of the CPUID instruction (basically the first code block in the OP) so it is NOT UNIQUE for processors of the same model !

Also, for it to get the actual HDD serial numbers and not just Volume ID (which can be changed easily with partition tools), "Hardware ID Extractor" requires to be run as administrator (elevated in case of Vista+ UAC), this making it completely useless for programs where you can't do that every launch (most of them).

Comment: At Rajkosto - It is actually good that it returns the real serial number as the volume ID is not permanent. The volume Id changes every time you format the volume. So, again: this is actually quite good. Also, you don't need to run the program EVERY TIME with elevated rights. It is enough to read the serial number ONCE when you install the program (an most programs run elevated anyway at installation) and store that number.

Comment: But then you cant verify the license against the stored serial number in the file every launch, only in elevated launches.
I'm only saying that BECAUSE you can get the serial number via WMI even when non-elevated, the "Hardware ID Extractor" software is just bad (and misleading, because they say the CPUID is unique)

Comment: WMI is a service and is NOT available/enabled in all computers. Do a google search and you will see why WMI is such a bad idea. MS has large resources that you can read about how to diagnose and (hopefully) fix WMI. They even lunched (yet another) a new FIX WMI tool: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff404265.aspx?f=255&MSPPError=-2147217396  _______ Simply put: WMI is nice... when it works :)